# Running Intellij with no 'Test' in the classname

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am running a simple JUnit test wherein I haven't defined my classname to be of the below mentioned :*Test,Test*,*TestCase types.

I am curious to know why Intellij passes all the tests but the same when am running from within console via Maven :mvn test,it shows No tests found.

I believe Maven's behaviour is quite correct but why does Intellij passes my tests?

My pom file is also very simple with just dependencies for JUnit and Selenium added.

If anyone can help me on this..

Comment: IntelliJ Idea uses its own test runner. If you want to achieve behavior you get when running command from console, use "Maven Projects" tab.

Comment: Another thing which one is best way for running my tests then,coz Maven doesn't recognize my tests if my classname doesnt have 'Test' in it.But then if I run via Intellij I might never come to know of this.I am new to Junit and Intellij.

Comment: Are your tests located in `src\test\java`, or some other place?

Comment: Maven Surefire plugin is by default configured to only check for classes that start or end with "Test", or end with "TestCase" (see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes). If you don't want to change your test classes names, just tell Maven to include everything you need.

Comment: yes,my tests are located in src\test\java ..What am confused about is, why Intellij's testrunner is different from Maven's?Thanks so much Tome for the info,but suppose I dont want to change my classname and I want Intellij to point out the same too..without running my tests via Maven.I hope I am clear.It's only when am running my tests from "Maven Projects" tab in Intellij can i make both results match.

Comment: *"why Intellij's testrunner is different from Maven's"*. Why wouldn't it? IntelliJ is an IDE that *can* use Maven and has great integration with it. But that doesn't mean that the team behind IntelliJ cannot develop something better (or different) than how Maven does it.

Comment: Thanks..yes there's no denying